# Liferay 7 Theme : docment.ready() not fired when changing page

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-7

I'm working on a liferay 7 theme and i've bound some JS on my main menu.
All my js is in a document.rdy event.
But what i can see is that when i change page, the document.ready() is not triggered, and all the js binding on my menu is lost.

How can i do?

Comment: Share your script code.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that too. If you don't need the liferay site to be a singlepage application, turn that feature off in portal-ext.properties:

```
javascript.single.page.application.enabled = false
```

and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(document).ready()` use `AUI().ready()`.
Liferay 7 uses SennaJS (SPA) therefore `$(document).ready()` is not fired when page is loaded (except on window reload).

see: 
https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/automatic-single-page-applications

and
https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/understanding-your-themes-javascript-callbacks-in-main-js

Comment: `AUI().ready()` is not invoked on SPA page navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Liferay.on("endNavigate")` lifecycle event of a SPA based Liferay app. Change your document ready code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function init() {
      console.log("Page loaded");
      // bind your events here.
   }
  
   init();

   Liferay.on("endNavigate", init);
 
});
```

`init` will be called as and when you navigate from one page to another.